# How to install MySQLdb on Mac OS X?

Tags: mysql-python

I want to install `MySQLdb` without using Conda

I already did this
https://ruddra.com/install-mysqlclient-macos/
and successfully installed to my mac:

```
 - MySQL
 - mysqlclient
 - mysql-connector-c
```

My final goal is to import MySQLdb to jypiter notebook and connect in order to write data to mysql database.

Could somebody please give me a step by step solution, what to do next, how to make it work?

I have MAC OS Mojave 10.14.5 / Python 3.9

when I do

```
pip install Mysqldb
```

i get an error

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement MySQLdb
ERROR: No matching distribution found for MySQLdb
```

when I do

```
pip install MySQL-python
```

i get another error:

```
WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/9a/81/924d6799494cf7fb24370335c2f782088d6ac4f79e4137d4df94cea3582c/MySQL-python-1.2.3.tar.gz#sha256=7de66fbbf923634e7c965aeaefa74642ba75ae20ee1cefcefc3009595b7a7e6e (from https://pypi.org/simple/mysql-python/). Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement MySQL-python
ERROR: No matching distribution found for MySQL-python
```

Comment: What "different ways" have you tried to install? You need to explain what you do to get that error, in order for the question to stand a chance of being on-topic. This might be off-topic for SO because it's not really about programming, but it's definitely off-topic if just asking for guides/examples.

Comment: You already have mysqlclient, which can be used to connect to MySQL from Jupyter notebook

Answer (score 1):

It turned out for Python3.x everything works great with PyMySQL :)

I have done

```
!python3 -m pip install PyMySQL
```

and

```
pymysql.connect(host = '....', 
                user = '....', 
                password = '....', 
                database = '....')
```